# image onLoad width is undefined

Tags: react-native, onload, zooming

When  running the following code without the ImageZoom component,the `useEffect` hook console logs this : `Object { "height": 412, "width": 231.66666666666666, }` which is the right height and width of the image on load (the size of the image as displayed).

but when im adding the `ImageZoom` component I get a Component Exception Cannot read property '`width`' of `undefined`.

```js
const ImageModal = ({ image, isOpenImage, onStateChange }) => {
  const [imageLoad, setImageLoad] = useState({ width: null, height: null });

  const handleLoad = (event) => {
    setImageLoad({
      width: event.nativeEvent.source.width,
      height: event.nativeEvent.source.height,
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(imageLoad);
  }, [imageLoad]);

  const NewImage = useCallback(
    () => (
      <Image
        onLoad={(event) => handleLoad(event)}
        source={image}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    ),
    []
  );

  return (
    <Modal
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      animationType="slide"
      transparent={true}
      visible={isOpenImage}>
      <Fragment>
        <View
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            backgroundColor: '#000000',
            opacity: 0.5,
          }}
        />

        <View
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            bottom: 22.5,
            zIndex: 2,
            alignSelf: 'center',
          }}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              onStateChange(false);
            }}
            style={{
              width: 130,
              height: 47,
              borderRadius: 50,
              borderWidth: 2,
              borderColor: '#fff',
              backgroundColor: '#2e423d',
              transform: [{ scaleX: 1 }],
              justifyContent: 'center',
            }}>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 18.8,
                fontFamily: 'OpenSansHebrew-Regular',
                color: '#ffffff',
                alignSelf: 'center',
              }}>
              סגירה
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            marginBottom: 0,
            marginHorizontal: 15,
            borderRadius: 20,
          }}>
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              backgroundColor: 'white',
              marginBottom: 0,

              marginBottom: 250,
              marginTop: 150,
              justifyContent: 'center',
            }}>
            <ImageZoom
              cropWidth={screenWidth}
              cropHeight={screenHeight}
              imageWidth={imageLoad.width}
              imageHeight={imageLoad.height}>
              <NewImage />
            </ImageZoom>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Fragment>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try initializing `imageLoad` state with some data.

```js
const [imageLoad, setImageLoad] = useState({width: 0, height: 0});
```

Comment: for the first time when a component renders, it has a value of undefined as you haven't initialized it in the useState hooks, that's why you will get that error, so to avoid that you have to give that value. and one more thing,  consider converting width and height to int by ```Math.floor()``` sometimes it causes weird behavior on iPhone.

Comment: Note that the component I’m talking about is ImageZoom, i initialized  the values to null now and ImageZoom gets imageLoad.width=null and imageLoad.height = null so its still not working and i cant see nothing on my iphone. hope you can help me solve it, thank you anyway!

Comment: and no console log as before

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the state imageLoad with an empty value. First of all you have to define the width and height of the value in your useState hook like this -

```
const [imageLoad, setImageLoad] = useState({width:null, height: null});
```

It's showing error because you have not defined your width and height objects in the state imageLoad.

according to your comment, it seems that your state is not updating before rendering of the ImageZoom component.

First try to update the state before the ImageZoom renders for that you can create a new state called imageLoaded and than update this state in your useEffect like this ->

```
    const [imageLoaded , setImageLoaded ] = useState(false);

     useEffect(() => {
getDimensions ()
      }, []);

const getDimensions = (url) => {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = ()=>  {  setImageLoad({
      width: img.width,
      height: img.height,
    })
setImageLoaded(true) }
}
```

Now render component On State of ImageLoad

```
ImageLoaded ? 
 <ImageZoom
              cropWidth={screenWidth}
              cropHeight={screenHeight}
              imageWidth={imageLoad.width}
              imageHeight={imageLoad.height}>
              <NewImage />
            </ImageZoom>
: null;
```

Now you don't need the onLoad event in your image component

Comment: Note that the component I’m talking about is ImageZoom, i defined the values now and ImageZoom gets imageLoad.width=null and imageLoad.height = null so its still not working. hope you can help me solve it, thank you anyway!

Comment: The reason is Your imageZoom component is rendering before the image load that is why it is taking initial values, to prevent this update the states before ImageZoom renders. For that you can use img object from javascript.

Comment: still not working, i have an error image is not a constructor, and i think it wont work anyway because im looking for the size of the image as displayed and not its real size.

Comment: in your code, it is already extracting the actual size in onLoad method, for that cause you would have to re-render the *parent component*  <ImageZoom/> and be sure that the next time onLoad event doesn't get executed.